# javascript in javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have this is in my javascript, but the javascript in the `document.getElementById` is not working.

```
document.getElementById('addcategory1').innerHTML += "<input type='text' class='input-short' name='newcategory[1]' value='New Category 2' onfocus='javascript: if(this.value == 'New Category 2'){ this.value = ''; }' onblur='javascript: if(this.value==''){this.value='New Category 2';}'/><br/><br/>";
```

This javascript is not working:

```
onfocus='javascript: if(this.value == 'New Category 2'){ this.value = ''; }'

onblur='javascript: if(this.value==''){this.value='New Category 2';}'
```

Comment: You need to escape your single quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is quoting problem here:

```
onfocus='javascript: if(this.value == 'New Category 2'){ this.value = ''; }' onblur='javascript: if(this.value==''){this.value='New Category 2';}'
```

You have nested single quote inside singe quote script.

Try replacing that with:

```
onfocus='if(this.value == "New Category 2'){this.value = ""; }' onblur='if(this.value==""){this.value="New Category 2";}'
```

Your bigger `innerHTML` code will be:

```
document.getElementById('addcategory1').innerHTML += "<input type='text' class='input-short' name='newcategory[1]' value='New Category 2' onfocus='if(this.value == \"New Category 2\"){ this.value = \"\"; }' onblur='if(this.value==\"\"){this.value=\"New Category 2\";}'/><br/><br/>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Escape the quotes properly. Use double quotes to envelop single quotes.

```
onfocus="javascript: if(this.value == 'New Category 2'){ this.value = ''; }" onblur="javascript: if(this.value==''){this.value='New Category 2';}"
```